# Using GraphicsPath::AddString() complains with "class 'GraphicsPath' has no member 'AddString'"

Tags: c++, gdi+, visual-studio-2019, cinder

I am trying to use the `GraphicsPath::AddString()` method of GDI+ in my libcinder project.

The idea is to create a path of a letter/glyph via the mentioned method and later pass that to `gl::draw()` and box2d's `b2FixtureDef`. The goal is create falling letters that show an exact collision behaviour.

However the following example taken from [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdipluspath/nf-gdipluspath-graphicspath-addstring(inconstwchar_inint_inconstfontfamily_inint_inreal_inconstpoint__inconststringformat)) throws several errors at me.

```
#include "cinder/app/App.h"
#include "cinder/app/RendererGl.h"
#include "cinder/gl/gl.h"
#include "cinder/Rand.h"
#include <Box2D/Box2D.h>

#include <gdiplus.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "gdiplus.lib")

using namespace Gdiplus;
using namespace ci;
using namespace ci::app;
using namespace std;

// ... 

void MyApp::draw()
{
  FontFamily fontFamily(L"Times New Roman");
    GraphicsPath path;

    // const WCHAR
    // Status AddString(
    //    IN const WCHAR         *string,
    //    IN INT                  length,
    //    IN const FontFamily    *family,
    //    IN INT                  style,
    //    IN REAL                 emSize,  // World units
    //    IN const PointF        &origin,
    //    IN const StringFormat  *format
    //)

  path.AddString(
    L"Hello World",
    -1,                 // NULL-terminated string
    &FontFamily("Arial"),
    FontStyleRegular,
    48,
    PointF(50.0f, 50.0f),
    NULL);
}
```

There are several issues with my code that just cant get fixed... My project's target platform version is 8.1 and the platform toolset is `Visual Studio 2015 (v140)`. The headers are there and can be browsed to when hitting F12.

1. `FontFamily fontFamily(L"Times New Roman");`

> "Cannot initialize local variable 'fontFamily' of type 'FontFamily'
>   with lvalue of type 'wchar_t const[16]'

2. `GraphicsPath path;`

> "No default constructor exists for class "GraphicsPath""

3. `path.AddString(...)`

> "class 'GraphicsPath' has no member 'AddString'"

Any help is very appreciated. I have spent hours with this issues with zero progress.

Comment: Always start at the top of the error list.  You need `#include <windows.h>` before the #include for gdiplus.h

Comment: Thx for replying. I have removed everything GDI-relevant but `FontFamily fontFamily(L"Times New Roman");` and added `#include <windows.h>`. But still now luck. Strangley VS throws several errors at me coming from `gdiplusbitmap.h` which is not included, nor part of my solution/project. Anything wrong with my project setup? Have SDK 8.1 and 10.x installed

Comment: It is included by gdiplus.h.  You won't get anywhere until the gdiplus*.h headers stop producing error messages.  Re-iterating, always start at the top of the error list, be very explicit about the error you see.  "throws several errors" doesn't help us help you.

Comment: You are using multiple `namespace`'s, maybe it's getting mixed up. Use `GdiPlus::FontFamily` instead.

Comment: Why the down-vote? Please comment so I can improve my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching high and low I figured it out. I was missing a couple of includes. But to be honest, I still don't really understand, why the compiler complained with that specific message...

The following does compile for me and produces the path coordinates for the letter "A".

```
// other includes
#include <windows.h>
#include <ObjIdl.h>
#include <minmax.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

using namespace Gdiplus;
using namespace ci;
using namespace ci::app;

#pragma comment (lib, "Gdiplus.lib")

// ...

void MyApp::setup()
{
  // ...

  GraphicsPath p(FillModeAlternate);
  FontFamily fontFamily(L"Arial");

  if (p.AddString(L"A", -1, &fontFamily, FontStyleRegular, 48, PointF(0.0f, 0.0f), NULL) != Status::Ok)
  {
    std::cout << "Error while adding points" << std::endl;
  }

  PointF points[64];

  if (p.GetPathPoints(points, sizeof(points)) != Status::Ok)
  {
    std::cout << "Error while getting points" << std::endl;
  }
}
```